# Сортировка в mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Имею документы вида:

```
{
 "_id": "648653b4f3767a7c85251656",
 "name": [{"lang":"ru", "value": "Яблоко"},{"lang":"en", "value": "Apple"}]
},
{
 "_id": "6486525fdb10e6f15ac41f6d",
 "name": [{"lang":"ru", "value": "Апельсин"},{"lang":"en", "value": "Orange"}]
}]
```

Задача отсортировать документы по алфавиту, в зависимости от языка.
Т.е. при запросе "lang": "ru", я получу [документ 2, документ 1], а  при запросе "lang": "en", я получу [документ 1, документ 2].

Я сортирую методами JavaScript, но полагаю, что методами mongodb сортировку можно сделать быстрее.

Подскажите, как это можно сделать методами mongodb?

Comment: У тебя очень неудачное строение данных... данные массива для сортировки документов вообще не годятся. Куда "ставить" документ если в массиве у него несколько значений. Переделывай `name` в объект типа `name: {ru: 'Яблоко', en: 'Apple'}` - тогда сортировка будет выглядеть так `('name.ru': 1)` или `('name.en': 1)`

Comment: @ksa написанное годится быть ответом

Comment: @ksa хороший ответ, спасибо

Comment: @nörbörnën, добавил ответ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> полагаю, что методами mongodb сортировку можно сделать быстрее

У тебя очень неудачное строение данных... Данные массива для сортировки документов вообще не годятся. Куда "ставить" документ если в массиве у него несколько значений.

Переделывай `name` в объект типа `name: {ru: 'Яблоко', en: 'Apple'}` - тогда сортировка будет выглядеть так `{'name.ru': 1}` или `{'name.en': 1}`